# Compile error using CocoaPods, RestKit with Dynamic Frameworks

Tags: ios, restkit, cocoapods

I am using CocoaPods and RestKit for a long time without any problems.
Since I am using Swift for some time now, I thought it was time to use CocoaPods with dynamic frameworks (available since 0.36.0)

However I run into a the following compile error: Use of undeclared type 'AFHTTPClient'

This is my PodFile (I am using tag 0.25.0 of RestKit since this release is ready for dynamic frameworks):

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.1'
inhibit_all_warnings!
use_frameworks!

pod 'RestKit', '0.25.0'

link_with ['TestProject', 'TestProjectTests']
```

I have one class:

```
import UIKit

import AFNetworking

class AFNetworingService {
    var client: AFHTTPClient?
}
```

This compiles fine!

Now I add another class:

```
import UIKit

import RestKit

class RestKitService {

}
```

Now compile fails with error: ***Use of undeclared type 'AFHTTPClient'*** in the AFNetworingService class

When I remove the 'import RestKit' from the RestKitService class, it compiles fine again

Somebody any ideas?